# Webpack tree-shaking removes side-effects code

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, tree-shaking, esmodules

I was testing out webpack tree-shaking behavior. As per the docs, any code that contains side-effects can be mentioned in the `sideEffects` property of package.json to inform webpack not to eliminate that module in the final build. I am leveraging this behavior to see if my entire module (helper.js) can be part of the final build, even though all the exported methods of that module are not used.

But in my case, this module is still getting tree-shaken. Can someone tell me what the reason might be?

Here is my code:

helper.js file

```
export default {
    helperMethod1: () => {
        console.log("This is helper method 1");
    },
    helperMethod2: () => {
        console.log("This is helper method 2");
    }
};
```

script.js

```
import helper from "./helper.js";
helper.helperMethod1()
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack"
  },
  "sideEffects": ["./helper.js"],
  ...
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    optimization: {
        sideEffects: true,
    }
}
```

Here is the final production build

```
(()=>{"use strict";console.log("This is a helper method 1")})();
```

I want `helperMethod2` to also be part of the final build. I know this is against optimization, but I just want to better understand webpack's tree-shaking behavior.

Comment: The way it is meant to work is when helper.js is its own npm module with its own package.json. Then you need to set sideEffect: true (not an array of strings) in that package.json not in the package.json of your main project.See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/examples/side-effects/README.md